# Relative importance of multiple correlated independent variables in logistic regression

Tags: logistic, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I have a multiple logistic regression with 11 independent variables (**x1** to **x11**). I have another 4 continuous IVs that are highly correlated with each other and correlated with **x11**. The 4 IVs along with x11 measure different KPIs but they are essentially related in some sense hence the correlation. I cannot include them all because of multicollinearity issues.

**X11** was included in the model since it gave the highest predictive performance on multiple test samples (in my case here, lift in the top decile).

I am being asked to measure the relative importance of each of the 4 IVs and x11 (rank them maybe) in relation to the dependent variable.

I have trying recycling them in the model and capture their  coefficients but I know that it’s not an accurate comparison since the coefficients of the other 10 variables slightly change.

I have thought about contribution to the log-likelihood of the model which will help me rank them but won’t tell me about enough about they relate to the dependent variable.

Your guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: How about partial correlation?

Comment: Partial correlation will not quantify the change in the dependent variable by changing the value of the covariate. It will certainly rank them though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility is to include all variables in the logistic regression model, and account for the multi-collinearity issues using ridge regression. This will appropriately penalize the coefficients of the correlates predictors and give you more stable results. I don't know which software you're using, but in R this is, for instance, available in the **glmnet** and **arm** packages.

Comment: Would the coefficients of the model have the same interpretation with ridge regression? I understand it penalizes the coefficients by adding some bias. Also, I am using R